# Laravel+Vue routing

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes

I am using Laravel+VueJs. I stuck on one thing. I am trying to load a new view using laravel route. I am using axios.

```
getRelatedChat(id) {
               return axios.get('/chat/'+id).then(({ data }) => {
                  // document.write(data)
                });
            }
```

The code of whole view is coming in console as output, but i want to load it like `window.url` does for us. Have no idea how to do.

Comment: Do you have SPA application? Or why do you need vue? Here is Laravel based SPA https://mcmpspb.ru/ without Vue. This is sources https://gitlab.com/Piterden/mcmp-pyro/tree/1.0/addons/default/defr/mcmp-theme/resources

Comment: I have just some chat application components in my application which i have to render in some place.

Comment: So try something and you will definitely reach some of your goals!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a nonsense. Actually there is no need to load the view. I can update some variable that are using on present component just like this:

```
   axios.get('/chat/json/'+id).then(({ data }) => {
                 this.messages =data.messages;
                 this.withUser = data.user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue has its own router. If you want to load a new page you can still use axios to get the data you want to show in the next page you want to open. Just try the [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/)

Comment: What about direct access to URLs and SEO?

Comment: I was just trying to avoid from that router because i don't need routing too much.